# Storing the grep output in loop

Tags: shell, grep

This grep commands prints the numbers (the count of groups merged)

```
 grep "merged" sombe_conversion_PSTN.sh.sql.log | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/ //g'
```

The Output is as follows:

```
1000000
41474
41543
83410
83153
83085
82861
82904
82715
41498
41319
```

I need to add the data from second to last row  of output and store it in a variable and
first element in a different variable.

for example :

```
var_num=1000000
sum_others=663962
```

How do i loop and add the variables?

Answer (score 1):

Do it twice. If your list of numbers is in the file `output`, do

```
$ var_num=$(cat output | head -1)
$ sum_others=$(cat output | sed '1d' | awk '{s += $1} END {print s}')
```